# Set magic quotes PHP error with legacy codeigniter site

Tags: php, codeigniter, deprecated

One of our legacy codeigniter sites has recently encountered the following problem - can anyone suggest the best way to fix this?

```
<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>
<p>Severity: 8192</p>
<p>Message:  Function set_magic_quotes_runtime() is deprecated</p>
<p>Filename: codeigniter/CodeIgniter.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 60</p>
```

Comment: Besides updating to the latest version, your other option is to open up `codeigniter/CodeIgniter.php` and comment line #60.

Comment: Newer versions of have Codeigniter have the error suppression operator preceeding it. You can add it to remove the error message. `@set_magic_quotes_runtime(0);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just decided to replace the line with the following:
ini_set("magic_quotes_runtime", 0);

Answer (score 2):

Aside from commenting out line 60 of that file, you should really consider disabling error output on production environment, if that's where you're seeing this error.

Errors can give attackers vital information sometimes, such as this one narrowing down your version number.